# Does all values which a static object went through take up space in memory while class is loaded?

Tags: java, memory, static, garbage-collection, jvm

I know that static variables are stored in a specific place in memory.  Whenever you declare an object as static, that object will never be recycled by gc as long as that class is loaded by the classloader .. so far so good.

But imagine that the variable that I defined as static has an internally non-static list, so even though the object itself will never be recycled, will that list be recycled normally? And even if I assign a new instance to a static object, will the old value not be recycled?  Would all the values ​​that this object went through take up space in memory?

Comment: That the reference to the list is `static` makes **no difference**.  The usual rules apply: when the old list becomes unreachable, it's a candidate for garbage collection. The only reason it _might_ hang around after the `static` reference has been changed would be if _something else_ held a reference to it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “static object”. Like any other variable, a `static` variable can only hold a *reference* to an object. That doesn’t change the nature of the object. Only `static final` variables inevitably refer to the same object throughout the class’ lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector starts its scanning from `gc roots`, one such root is a `static` field.

So a `GC` will traverse all entries that "start" from this root, for example:

```
   SomeStaticInstance
          |
         \ /
     NonStaticList
```

If `NonStaticList` is reachable (`marking` phase of the gc phases takes care of this), it is considered alive and thus not eligible for `GC`. If it is not reachable, it is eligible for collection. Notice that if it is not reachable, `mark phase` will not even traverse anything that might have references *from* `NonStaticList`:

```
 NonStaticList
       |
      \ /
    RefHere
```

So `RefHere` is not going to be scanned. It *might* get scanned if it has references from somewhere else to it, but not from `NonStaticList`.